# ExtJs dynamic delegate for ComboBox

Tags: extjs, combobox, delegates

In a normal Panel in ExtJs, you can attach a delegate listener dynamically by doing the following;

```
cmp.el.on('click', function() {
    console.log("click on span");
}, null, {delegate: 'span.testclick1'});
```

However, in a combobox using a custom template, I can't use this same method. I think it might be due to a listConfig that ComboBox's expect.

I say this because in the following link, it is used;
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?158991-ComboBox-custom-template-how-do-I-attach-a-click-handler

I just can't use the same format since I'm on an older version of ExtJs

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what version are you on?

Comment: I am on version 3.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the other events for comboBox, such as `expand` or `focus` or `select`

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-event-expand

Comment: The problem I have right now is that I would like to attach more than one listener per row. Like a button next to the text -- none of the properties above will give me that.